# How to create Magento Module to display webservice

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. I would like to get a good tutorial and example for creating module to display webservice . Please suggest to me some websites that explain these things in a simple way.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43818/), or [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/custom_api_complete_example) but this is just for API v1. 
There is a good explanation on how the API works on [Alan Storm's blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_api_soap_adapaters_and_handlers)
I also recommend trying out the [Ultimate Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html). beside the fact that you ca build your module in a few clicks with it, it also has an option to generate the API files for your module (v1, v2 and WS-I compliant).

---

<sub>Don't consider this as self promotion. The extension I recommended is created by myself, but it's free and does not bring me any financial benefits.</sub>